It appears that Dramatiq with asyncio operates with just a single worker
I am trying to run several jobs in parallel.
When I define actor as a sync function it uses different workers.
But when functions is async it uses only one thread(worker).
I generally understand difference between asynchronous parallelism and multithreading/multiprocessing, but is there a way to use all spawned workers with async actors?
For example, if you are limited by library you use inside actor.
I don't feel make actor synchronous and spawn new event loop inside it as an elegant solution though.
The code I use:
redis_broker = RedisBroker(
    host=settings.redis_url,
    port=settings.redis_port,
    db=settings.redis_db,
    password=settings.redis_password,
    middleware=[CurrentMessage()]  # with AsyncIO() in async case
)
dramatiq.set_broker(redis_broker)

Sync actor:
@dramatiq.actor
def jobs(param: int):
    logger.info(f"Started {param}")
    time.sleep(param)
    logger.info(f"Ended {param}")

Async actor:
@dramatiq.actor
async def jobs(param: int):
    logger.info(f"Started {param}")
    await asyncio.sleep(param)
    logger.info(f"Ended {param}")

And I run it as:
g = group([
    jobs.send(1),
    jobs.send(2),
    jobs.send(3),
]).run()

Sync results:
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,251] [PID 420038] [Thread-3] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 3
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,251] [PID 420038] [Thread-5] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 2
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,251] [PID 420038] [Thread-6] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 3
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,252] [PID 420038] [Thread-7] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 1
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,252] [PID 420038] [Thread-8] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 2
[2024-10-11 02:38:42,252] [PID 420038] [Thread-4] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 1
[2024-10-11 02:38:43,253] [PID 420038] [Thread-7] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 1
[2024-10-11 02:38:43,254] [PID 420038] [Thread-4] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 1
[2024-10-11 02:38:44,254] [PID 420038] [Thread-5] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 2
[2024-10-11 02:38:44,254] [PID 420038] [Thread-8] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 2
[2024-10-11 02:38:45,255] [PID 420038] [Thread-6] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 3
[2024-10-11 02:38:45,255] [PID 420038] [Thread-3] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 3

Async results:
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 3
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 2
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 3
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 1
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 2
[2024-10-11 02:50:03,245] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Started 1
[2024-10-11 02:50:04,246] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 1
[2024-10-11 02:50:04,246] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 1
[2024-10-11 02:50:05,247] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 2
[2024-10-11 02:50:05,247] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 2
[2024-10-11 02:50:06,246] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 3
[2024-10-11 02:50:06,246] [PID 422276] [Thread-1] [dramatiq] [INFO] Ended 3


Dramatiq handles running of async actors in a separate thread with a single event loop: https://github.com/Bogdanp/dramatiq/blob/a11a459ecb01c105837ce446f5d218824ea9a3e1/dramatiq/asyncio.py#L72
It does not even schedule actors as tasks on the event loop and just blocks on every coroutine. So yeah, it's better to not use async actors at all or spawn a loop inside a task manually:
async def _async_actor():
  pass

@dramatiq.actor
def async_actor():
    asyncio.run(_async_actor())

